# github3.py authorisation lost tokens / multiple machines

Tags: github-api, github3.py

I am probably doing something stupid, but...

When attempting to retrieve a token with code like this:

`auth = github3.authorize(user, password, scopes, note, two_factor_callback = two_factor_callback)`

I'm finding that the API creates a token, which I then store locally, and all is hunky dory.

If however I lose the locally stored token, or move to another machine where the token is not stored locally, I get a failure back from authorize.

It seems that once a token is created for a given `note` value, it cannot be obtained again, or overwritten with a new one.

For changes of machine, I suspect that the `fingerprint` parameter in the github API needs to be implemented. A temporary workaround is to salt the `note` value with something unique to the machine you're on, such as the MAC address, but that's a bit ugly.

For the situation where the token exists, but the local copy of it has been lost (by the user deleting it from the keychain where I've stored it, for example), the only solution seems to be to log on to the github website and manually remove the token!

That's a bit counter-intuitive to me! What am I missing here?

I can see that perhaps github's servers don't store the entire token, so can't return it again - but in that case I'd expect a clean way to be able to regenerate it. Maybe there is one, and I'm missing it?

Answer (score 0):

> For the situation where the token exists, but the local copy of it has been lost (by the user deleting it from the keychain where I've stored it, for example), the only solution seems to be to log on to the github website and manually remove the token!

You should be able to access the list of authorizations with the user's username & password. If you can find the existing one, you should be able to delete it.

> I can see that perhaps github's servers don't store the entire token, so can't return it again

I suspect they *do* store it. They just refuse to return it.

> but in that case I'd expect a clean way to be able to regenerate it. Maybe there is one, and I'm missing it?

As far as I know, there is no way to regenerate an Authorization Token. GitHub doesn't make the generation algorithm public and there's no way to retrieve a token after it's first generated.